# Give an example of two functions such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$. But $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis

Give an example of two functions $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, $g:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$, such as $\forall x>0$, $f(x)>0$ and $g(x)>0$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ does not exist.

I was thinking that maybe $f(x)g(x)$ should be a trigonometric function (specifically sine or cosine), this way $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)g(x)$ would not exist, however I am unable to propose two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ that fulfill the conditions stated at the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a good idea: start with proposing what the product $f(x)g(x)$ could be, and then construct the individual $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ from that. And the idea to use trigonometric functions sounds really good to me too! We just need to make it work.

First of all, since all functions have to be strictly positive, we can't simply use "$f(x)g(x)=\sin x$" (or cosine). But we can raise its graph vertically to make it strictly positive; for example, let's say $f(x)g(x)=3+\sin x$.

Notice this function is bounded: $2\le3+\sin x\le4$. Now take your favorite positive function that goes to $+\infty$ to be $f(x)$. Then this $f(x)$ and $g(x)=\dfrac{3+\sin x}{f(x)}$ will work.

Answer (score 2):

How about: $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$? Then $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} x = +\infty$.

Another example: $f(x) = x (\sin^2{x}+1)$ and $g(x) = \frac{\sin^2{x}+1}{x}$.

Comment: Your first example is excellent! But your second example doesn't work, because both functions are required to be positive.

Comment: @zipirovich you're right, thank you! But it's eazy to fix - by squaring or adding a constant